# Setting "R Folder" Path in QGIS Sextante

Tags: qgis, r, sextante

I have installed R via the [R-Project website](http://probability.ca/cran/). I have QGIS installed via OSGEO4W (currently 1.9.0 Master), and have Sextante plugin installed and working with GRASS and SAGA providers. I am now trying to get R to run, but with no luck. I initially installed R to Program Files, but found mention that perhaps the space in the file path was an issue, so I have re-installed to C:\R\R-3.0.1\

What paths do I need to enter the "R Folder" and "RScripts Folder" configuration area in Sextante? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with the plugin not supporting the new SIP API? The fix below only works on the stable version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm going to see if this bug is related (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8012).

**UPDATE:** Looks like there are some issues with R in the sextante plugin for both qgis and qgis-dev.
I'll file some bug reports if they haven't been already. But the two issues with R in sextante are:

1) In qgis (stable) SEXTANTE doesn't seem to use the rlib path in the Users .qgis folder. Instead it relies on the default R library path in C:/. The plugin will still download and install the missing libraries into the qgis sextante plugin folder but won't actually use them. You have to install them from R manually - eg, `install.packages("rgdal")`

2) In qgis-dev (unstable) SEXTANTE doesn't launch any R scripts and gives a warning about missing dependencies and that R is not properly installed. This is the OPs problem.

---

2. Install R like you have.
3. Install and open QGIS, install the SEXTANTE plugin like you've also done
4. Select the pull-down menu **Analysis** > **SEXTANTE options and configuration**
5. Expand **R scripts** in the ***Sextante options*** window and set the **R folder** to your R directory *(ie, C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1)*. You don't have to worry about **R Scripts folder** unless you have a different place where you store your RScripts.

Now the funny part, possibly a bug...

Try to run one of the **R scripts** in the ***SEXTANTE Toolbox***, like **Create regular sampling grid**.

This fails, with the helpful error:

```
options("repos"="http://cran.us.r-project.org") 
tryCatch(find.package("rgdal"), error=function(e) install.packages("rgdal", lib="C:/Users/userman/.qgis//sextante/rlibs")) 
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/rgdal_0.8-9.zip' 
Content type 'application/zip' length 11911822 bytes (11.4 Mb) 
opened URL 
downloaded 11.4 Mb 

package 'rgdal' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked 

The downloaded binary packages are in 
C:\Users\userman\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyEEQJa\downloaded_packages 
library("rgdal") 
Error in library("rgdal") : there is no package called 'rgdal' 
Execution halted 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm Create regular sampling grid finished
```

The plugin is downloading and installing the libraries to it's custom rlib path, but when it goes to run the actual tool/script, it's not searching that path - but instead the default system rlib path.

The FIX - Install the needed library from the R interface *(ie, launch R directly)*. Then go back to QGIS and launch the scripts.

Now they run! Output of random sample grid:

[image: Result of R Random Sample Grid script in SEXTANTE Toolbox for QGIS]

Comment: Thanks Don. When I run a script, I don't get the message you show. I get:  "Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-( It seems that R is not correctly installed in your system. Please install it before running R Scripts."  I am new at R, but I think managed to install rgdal and SP from the R GUI directly (not sure how via command line), and they appear to have worked. Opening QGIS again results in the same error as above.

Comment: If the path to the R Folder is correct, and it still gives a problem, can you see if it's an issue with the architecture type of R (ie, 32bit vs 64bit?). Maybe try installing R with both the 32 and 64bit. SEXTANTE in QGIS might need a specific arch of R to run scripts. I know QGIS from OSGEO4W is 32bit.

Comment: I installed both 32 and 64 bit versions of R, and tried with the "Use 64 bit version" option box checked and unchecked, in the Sextante options, with no luck.

Comment: One last thing I can think of before I get home to test it on a fresh VM is, in your Users folder, delete _(or just rename)_ the *sextante* folder in the .qgis folder? That sextante folder can hold some conflicting settings or history.

Comment: Interesting; I have both a .qgis and a .qgis2 folder in my users directory. I renamed the sextante folder in .qgis, and nothing changed. I renamed the one in .qgis2, and a new setante folder was created, leading me to believe it is using .qgis2 - however, this still did not work after resetting the R Folder path in the options menu. Perhaps there's something about the qgis2 folder that is causing issues? Are these folders auto-created? Can I just delete both and start fresh?

Comment: Those folders are there so that one stores your settings for qgis and the other for qgis-dev (master). It's part of what lets you run them both on the same PC. If you want to try deleting/renaming, it's safe to do so, **but** it resets the entire QGIS user interface back to default and you will probably have to re-install the plugins you had before too (they're in the plugins folder).

Comment: Thanks SaultDon; I'm still having no luck. I deleted .qgis2 and re-set the R Folder and am getting the same error.

Comment: @DarrenCope Looks like it might be a bug in SEXTANTE for QGIS 1.9 (master). I've updated the bug report at http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8012 and we'll have to wait for the plugin maintainer/dev to give it some attention. In the meantime, SEXTANTE/R works in QGIS 1.8 (stable).

Comment: Thanks SaultDon; I tried it in 1.8, and it works fine! Figures! Sorry for all the hassle, and thanks for your time! Now, I just need to learn a bit about R! :)

Comment: @DarrenCope Any chance you have figured this out for QGIS 2.0 which now has Processing installed by default instead of SEXTANTE. I am having trouble running the example R scripts that come with it. I get the same error message as you had before of "Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-( It seems that R is not correctly installed in your system.

Comment: @user19351 I had a small permissions issue on Windows 8.1 and just had to give my user full read/write access to the R folder. But you might have to set the R path first in Processing>Options and Configuration>Providers>R>R folder (C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0).

Comment: @SaultDon Thanks so much for that tip. It was just the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue, and slightly differently under Ubuntu and under Windows.

On Ubuntu, Sextante found R but couldn't run any of the scripts despite the relevant libraries having been installed from the R console. It looks like Sextante wants to use a different library store to the default which happens to be in a protected system folder, so my workaround was to run QGIS as a superuser once to load each script in turn so it could install the libraries it wanted, where it wanted. Afterwards it was happy to load as a normal user until the next time I need a library it doesn't see.

On Windows, I also had an issue where it wouldn't reliably set the R folder. There was nothing wrong with my R installation, it loaded fine in any manner except from within Sextante. When I looked in the Sextante folder in .qgis, the conf file was pointing to a different location than was set in the options menu. Manually correcting this seemed to solve the problem.

I then needed to run QGIS as an admin, as with Ubuntu, to ensure it loaded the libraries it needed, where it needed - again this is only needed when you first need a new library Sextante isn't aware of.

Essentially, for whatever reason, Sextante's R set-up seems to be broken from a users perspective but at least there's a workaround.

(The same works for the "Processing" plugin nuder QGIS 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that R is installed under Program Files by default, which is write-protected. Install R into another folder such as C:\R\R-3.1.3 and the problem goes away when you set it as the R path in QGIS. The solution is described here: http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/R_installation

This worked running QGIS 2.8.1 Wien on Windows 7 64-bit.