# Accessing R from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r

I have been unable to run R from within QGIS on my computer. I have R version 3.03 installed and QGIS 2.4 on Windows 7. R is located at C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\and this is the path e specified in Processing Options -> Providers -> R Scripts -> R Folder in QGIS.

The error message I receive is

```
Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
This algorithm requires R to be run.Unfortunately, it seems that R is not installed
in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used from QGIS 
Click here to know more about how to install and configure R to be used with QGIS
```

I have tried changing the R folder to other R executables, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried setting the path to R contained within QGIS? Here is an example of my path for the R Script folder: _C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\r_

Comment: The path maps to my currently installed version of R. When I install QGIS, it does not appear to install R and I am not sure why. I would like to have an R version embedded in QGIS, but it does not give me this option.

Comment: Should not "R folder" be the R install directory, and not the bin directory.
For example C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1, as suggested in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63922/setting-r-folder-path-in-qgis-sextante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that R is installed under Program Files by default, which is write-protected. Install R into another folder such as C:\R\R-3.1.3 and the problem goes away when you set it as the R path in QGIS. The solution is described here: http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/R_installation

This worked running QGIS 2.8.1 Wien on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip. Actually I placed the bin folder in R folder (C:\R\R-3.3.0\bin) and I continued to get the Missing Dependency dialog. Once I modified to **C:\R\R-3.3.0**, everything just worked like magic!