# Update vector layer field drop down list in R QGIS processing

Tags: r, qgis-processing

I want to select a certain field (*X*) from an input vector layer in my R processing script. In the below example, I want to be able to select the field (*X*) from the input (*Layer*). But the actual model always shows the fields (*X*) of the first (alphabetical) point layer in my QGIS project. It should reactively update the field drop down list according to which layer I selected.

```
##showplots 
##Layer=vector point 
##X=Field Layer
boxplot(Layer[[X]])
```

[image: The user interface of the model. I want X to be updated according to which layer I select.]

Comment: Is this just the way QGIS works? It always gives a list of the layers, and you want it to pre-select the current QGIS selected layer? That would require some changes to the QGIS processing system - have you checked the QGIS tracker to see if anyone has suggested this already? Or add a new request there?

Comment: @Spacedman I think we are talking about different things: I want to select a certain field of the input layer. This works fine in many of the standart QGIS tools. I think the issue is that I haven't understood how R processing in QGIS works... if I click run (in my coded scripts) nothing happens, although if I run the standard R pre-installed scripts (from the plugin) they run fine.

Comment: Ah okay. This works for me. My first layer has columns A and B, my second has C and D. Running the script originally shows me the first layer with an empty X, which drops down A and B. If I change to the second layer I see C and D on the drop down. What version of QGIS and R Processing Plugin are you using? QGIS: 3.26.3-Buenos Aires and 
processing_r: 3.1.1 here (see Help... About... for versions)

Comment: After I did the same test as you it still didn't work. I thought it must be some underlying problem. I found this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112061/accessing-r-from-qgis and reinstalled R on my C drive. This worked!! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

R needs to be installed in a folder with writing rights (Windows). [Accessing R from QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112061/accessing-r-from-qgis)

This solved the problem and all R scripts worked.